# Maven: Downloading a parent pom from the repository deletes repositories tag

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent-pom stored on a remote Artifactory repository. The parent-pom defines a `<repositories>` tag with some snapshot repositories that contain the parent of my parent-pom.

When I now try to build a project using my parent-pom, maven correctly finds the parent-pom in my Artifactory repository and downloads it.

During the build process my snapshot dependencies can't be found however, since the parent-pom that eventually ends up in my local repository is missing the `<repositories>` tag.

It works fine if I just run `mvn clean install` in the directory of the parent-pom to install it locally, but downloading it from the repository seems to get rid of the tag.

This seems to me like a bug, but maybe I'm missing something and this is intended behaviour? If so, why? Is there some workaround we can use to make it possible to define the repositories in the parent-pom?

Parent-pom as stored on the artifactory server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.0.M2</version>
     </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.1</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>example-parent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>example-releases</id>
            <name>example-releases</name>
            <url>http://com.example/blabla</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>example-snapshots</id>
            <name>example-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://com.example/blabla</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Parent-pom as downloaded from the repository when building my child project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.0.M2</version>
     </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.1</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>example-parent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>





    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>example-releases</id>
            <name>example-releases</name>
            <url>http://com.example/blabla</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>example-snapshots</id>
            <name>example-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://com.example/blabla</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

(even including some whitespace where the tags used to be)

Comment: tried to delete it from local repo and "mvn clean install -U" ?

Comment: Yes, it downloads the pom from artifactory, but compilation of the child project fails, because the spring boot dependencies can't be found. Looking in the local repo afterwards shows me that the tag was deleted again.
Installing the parent pom locally and then trying to compile the child works fine, but is not really practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifctory may filter out repository tags under certain circumstances, see [[RTFACT-5343] Artifactory removes the pom <repositories> tag when accessing from a virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5343):

> This is actually a feature of Artifactory to make sure maven will only work against your Artifactory server.
>
> Once maven encounter the repository tag inside the pom it try to download the dependencies from this repositories, shortcutting your repository manager. The file it self is saved un touched inside the repository.
>
> You can turn it off in the virtual repository config panel
>   http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories